# handsontable unaligned columns

Tags: javascript, multiple-columns, handsontable

I'm using handsontable for alot of data/rows and when I scroll up and down or sort, the columns sometimes becomes unaligned with the header row cells.

Image:
[image: img]

I'm using '//handsontable.com/dist/handsontable.full.css' and '//handsontable.com/dist/handsontable.full.js' as my sources, which are currently pointing to v.0.20.0.

Here's my init code:

```
window.hoTable = new Handsontable($("#results")[0], {
    data: cleansedArray, //array of arrays
    colHeaders: ["Title", "Site", "Dates", "Links", "Non-product Links", "Meta", "Categories", "Tags", "Products", "Images"],
    rowHeaders: false,
    stretchH: 'all',
    columnSorting: true,
    contextMenu: false,
    className: "htLeft htMiddle",
    readOnly: true,
    colWidths: [10, 5, 10, 5, 8, 18, 6, 6, 16, 16],
    columns: [
            { data: 0, type: 'text', editor: false, disableVisualSelection: true, renderer: titleRenderer },
            { data: 1, type: 'text', editor: false, disableVisualSelection: true, renderer: siteRenderer },
            { data: 2, type: 'text', editor: false, disableVisualSelection: true, renderer: datesRenderer },
            { data: 3, type: 'text', editor: false, disableVisualSelection: true, renderer: linksRenderer },
            { data: 4, type: 'text', editor: false, disableVisualSelection: true, renderer: nonproductLinksRenderer },
            { data: 5, type: 'text', editor: false, disableVisualSelection: true, renderer: metaRenderer },
            { data: 6, type: 'text', editor: false, disableVisualSelection: true, renderer: categoriesRenderer },
            { data: 7, type: 'text', editor: false, disableVisualSelection: true, renderer: tagsRenderer },
            { data: 8, type: 'text', editor: false, disableVisualSelection: true, renderer: productsRenderer },
            { data: 9, type: 'text', editor: false, disableVisualSelection: true, renderer: imagesRenderer }
    ]
});
```

Anyone else experiencing this? Thanks in advance, much appreciated!

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle so that we can see the issue? It looks like you have extra CSS there which could be conflicting

Comment: Here it is on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v9puxLsz/3/ although I'm not experiencing the problem there.

I did do some more research and the problem is that the header cells of the table are just fine, the problem is with the '.ht_clone_top' table. I used the temporary fix from here: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/1713 and so far that CSS rule of hiding the 2nd table is working.

Comment: right just remember that if you do that, you won't be able to 'freeze' columns as that is what that clone table is used for